# Is there a way to use a DataAccessor from Jena to use the graph store protocol with Virtuoso?

Tags: sparql, jena, virtuoso, graph-store-protocol

I tried to insert a dataset using a DataAccessor from jena withL

```
DatasetAccessor authAcc = DatasetAccessorFactory.createHTTP("http://192.168.56.101:8890/sparql-graph-crud-auth", auth);
authAcc.putModel("oole:g1",dataset.getDefaultModel());
```

But it does not seem to work, I also tried to PUT the same file using curl and I spotted a difference in the HTTP header.

From jena:

```
PUT /sparql-graph-crud-auth?graph=oole:g1 HTTP/1.1
```

While from curl doing:

```
curl --digest --user usr:pwd --verbose --url "http://192.168.56.101:8890/sparql-graph-crud-auth?graph-uri=oole:g1" -T file.ttl
```

I get:

```
PUT /sparql-graph-crud-auth?graph-uri=oole:g1 HTTP/1.1
```

The difference seems to be graph-uri as oppsed to graph. Is there any way i can still use the DataAccessor from Jena?

Answer (score 0):

`DatasetAccessor` is the API to the SPARQL Graph Store Protocol and there it says `graph=`.  This is wired into `DatasetAccessorGraphHTTP`.

Being open source, if you need something different you could take a copy of that one class, modify it locally (method `DatasetAccessorGraphHTTP.target`) to have your own implementation.

It is all built on top of some HTTP convenience code in `HttpOp` which you could call directly but your own modified `DatasetAccessorGraphHTTP` looks to be less work.